# How does a servo hold its position without drawing too much current?

Tags: arduino, current, servo

In a standard DC motor if you supply a voltage and stop it from rotating i.e. applying a heavy load, it will draw a lot of current. How is this not the case with a Servo? How does it hold its position and resist changes in its position without drawing a lot of current?

Comment: What they said - **BUT** note that systems with strong "saliency" in the motor proper may have strong hold in force per current compared to the rotational force provided when moving. A classic stepper motor is such a system - when the steeper motor is at rest the "iron" core pieces (poles) are at point of closest approach and so provide maximum force per current. Some systems provide a certain holding current and a greater or much greater drive or stepping current. | Note that "Servo" can mean a hobby device that has a geared motor and a pot for position feed back OR denote a "servomotor" ...

Answer (score 7):

Your assumption isn't true.  If there's a force trying to move the servo from the setpoint, it will draw considerable current, like any other motor.

Answer (score 4):

Largely, what they said - BUT:

Note that systems with strong "saliency" (ie magnetic force changes greatly as rotor poles pass stator poles) in the motor proper may have strong hold in force per current compared to the rotational force provided when moving.
A classic stepper motor is such a system - when the stepper motor is at rest the "iron" core pieces (poles) are at point of closest approach and so provide maximum force per current. Some systems provide a certain holding current and a greater or much greater drive or stepping current.

---

Note that "Servo" can mean a hobby device that has a geared motor and a pot for position feed back OR denote a "servomotor" which is usually a precision & high performance control system motor drive with position and/or velocity and/or rate feedback which may or may not be geared. I assume you mean geared motor the hobby device.

In a geared system the torque required to turn the drive motor by moving the output shaft depends greatly on the mechanical design. Non-overhauling gearboxes are not common, apart from worm-drive systems, but are possible:

- If you have a worm drive system where a N tooth gear drives a worm screw which is effectively a 1 tooth gear (for a single start worm) then it is often (by design) IMPOSSIBLE to turn the drive motor by attempting to move the output shaft. Such a system will main the output position against any load (that does not destroy it) with no input power to the motor.
- In a gearbox system with a "cascade" of gears it may or may not be possible to turn the motor by turning the output shaft. The ability to do so is known as "overhauling" and depends on certain mechanical arrangements being met. These are a function of tooth angle, pitch, friction and more. The worm drive is essentially the limiting case of a system that does not allow overhauling. It is possible to design a system that will necessarily "lock up" rather than 'overhaul'. This allows position to be held with no input power - apart from motion due to backlash in the gears or other mechanical non idealities.
- A true "servomotor" system could use a non overhauling gearbox system so that the load could be held in position with zero input.

Answer (score 2):

The torque/force exerted my a servo motor is directly proportional to the current.  If a servo is told to hold position and a force is applied to the load, the servo will need to apply an equal and opposite force to hold position.  The higher the force the more current will be required.

So, as already stated, your assumption is incorrect.  Most notably, holding a heavy vertical load in position can take considerable current/power, sometimes alleviated with the use of a brake.